# Key element does not match the schema with DocumentClient

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a Lambda that I have created using the [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudiocode/). I have a small lambda.js file that exports the handler for API Gateway events.

```js
const App = require('./app');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    let config = { 
        aws_region: 'us-east-1',
        //endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',
    };

    let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    let app = new App(dynamo, config, event);

    try {
        let response = await app.run();
        return response;
    } catch(err) {
        return err;
    }
};
```

The app.js file represents the logic of my Lambda. This is broken up to improve testing.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

class App {
    constructor(datastore, configuration, event) {
        this.datastore = datastore;
        this.httpEvent = event;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    async run() {
        AWS.config.update({
            region: this.configuration.aws_region,
            endpoint: this.configuration.endpoint,
        });

        let params = {
            TableName: 'test',
            Key: {
                'year': 2015,
                'title': 'The Big New Movie',
            },
        };
        const getRequest = this.datastore.get(params);

        // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        var result = await getRequest.promise();

        let body = {
            location: this.configuration.aws_region,
            url: this.configuration.endpoint,
            data: result
        };

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': JSON.stringify(body)
        };
    }
}

module.exports = App;
```

I can write the following mocha test and get it to pass.

```js
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const App = require('../app');

const expect = chai.expect;
var event, context;

const dependencies = {
    // sinon.stub() prevents calls to DynamoDB and allows for faking of methods.
    dynamo: sinon.stub(new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()),
    configuration: {
        aws_region: 'us-west-2',
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:5000',
    },
};

describe('Tests handler', function () {
    // Reset test doubles for isolating individual test cases
    this.afterEach(sinon.reset);

    it('verifies successful response', async () => {
        dependencies.dynamo.get.returns({ promise: sinon.fake.resolves('foo bar')});
        let app = new App(dependencies.dynamo, dependencies.configuration, event);
        const result = await app.run()

        expect(result).to.be.an('object');
        expect(result.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(result.body).to.be.an('string');
        console.log(result.body);
        let response = JSON.parse(result.body);

        expect(response).to.be.an('object');
        expect(response.location).to.be.equal(dependencies.configuration.aws_region);
        expect(response.url).to.be.equal(dependencies.configuration.endpoint);
        expect(response.data).to.be.equal('foo bar');
    });
});
```

However, when I run the Lambda locally using the `Debug Locally` via the Code Lens option in VS Code the results from the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.get` call throws an exception.

```json
{
  "message":"The provided key element does not match the schema",
  "code":"ValidationException",
  ...
  "statusCode":400,
  "retryable":false,
  "retryDelay":8.354173589804192
}
```

I have a table created in the us-east-1 region where the non-test code is configured to go to. I've confirmed the http endpoint being hit by the `DocumentClient` as being `dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. The table name is correct and I have a hash key called `year` and a sort key called `title`. Why would this not find the key correctly? I pulled this example from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.02), created a table to mirror what the key was and have not had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the Key `year` was provided a number value while the table was expecting it to be a string.

Wrapping the `2015` in quotes let the Document know that this was a string and it could match to the schema in Dynamo.

```
let params = {
    TableName: 'test',
    Key: {
        'year': '2015',
        'title': 'The Big New Movie',
    },
};
```